# Simple select from MongoDB with vibed

Tags: mongodb, d, vibed

I am learning how to use MongoDB from vibed. I wrote simple app, that as I am thinking should do find operation. But when I run it I am getting error: `Querying uninitialized MongoCollection.`. What I am doing wrong?

```
import vibe.core.log;
import vibe.db.mongo.mongo;
import vibe.d;
import std.stdio;

import std.array;

void main()
{
    MongoCollection m_posts;
    foreach(p;m_posts.find("{}"))
    {
        writeln(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [mongo example](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/blob/master/examples/mongodb/source/app.d) in vibe.d repository.

It comes down to this pattern:

```
void main()
{   
    auto db = connectMongoDB("localhost").getDatabase("test");
    auto coll = db["collection"];
    foreach (i, doc; coll.find("{}"))
        writeln("Item %d: %s", i, doc.toJson().toString());      
}
```

In your snippet you have attempted to use collection object without actually connecting to the database and retrieving it from there. This is exactly what error is about.

Answer (score 0):

You just created the MongoCollection object and did not initialized it with anything. That's why the error is about an "Uninitialized Collection". You should connect it to a database and put some data in it. Have a look at http://vibed.org/api/vibe.db.mongo.collection/MongoCollection for examples.